# Why the graph is not proper in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I wanted to plot the graph from the adjacency matrix. As a first step, I have tried the following code.

```
   set.seed(1)
   library('igraph');
   adjm1<-matrix(sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.9,01)),nc=10); 
   g1<-graph.adjacency(adjm1); 
   plot(g1)
```

But it gave me, the following graph.

[image]

### What is the mistake here?

PS: I am using

```
Rstudio Version 1.1.442 
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: Did you try to increase the plots pane in Rstudio?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, even without increasing the plots pane. BTW, would you mind setting the RNG seed with `set.seed()` in order to have reproducible results?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have edited the question with `set.seed()`. Will it still have the same output i had?? I am not sure. `set.seed()` is not machine dependent??

Comment: @ANG I have done that.. I have zoomed the fig and seen.. still same results.

Comment: In RStudio version 1.1.453 on ubuntu 18.04 I still cannot reproduce this. The arrows are much smaller. `help("plot.igraph")` has a link to `igraph.plotting` with a list of graphic parameters that `plot.igraph` accepts but the `arrow.*` parameters seem to have no effect at all. Also, `set.seed()` is not machine dependent.

Comment: I get the same result as David when I plot the graph within the RStudio plotting panel on Windows. However if you call `windows; plot(g1)` the plot is normally proportioned

Comment: @Esther Still I get the same kind of graph..All the arrows are big I thing.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yeah.. you are right.. I have checked two different machine with `set.seed()`, produces the same result.

Comment: Try, plot(g, edge.arrow.size = 0.5) . From similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687588/igraph-plotting-directed-network-creates-triangular-edges/50687628#50687628

Comment: @Dave2e This worked for me with `edge.arrow.size = 0.1`. Can you make this as answer so that I can accept it.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for whatever reason the default arrow size on your system is too large.  One can specify the arrow size in the plot statement. Example: `edge.arrow.size = 0.5`

```
set.seed(1)
library('igraph');

adjm1<-matrix(sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.9,01)),nc=10); 
g1<-graph.adjacency(adjm1); 

plot(g, edge.arrow.size = 0.1)
```

From similar question: [igraph - plotting directed network creates triangular edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687588/igraph-plotting-directed-network-creates-triangular-edges/50687628#50687628)