# igraph - plotting directed network creates triangular edges

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to plot a directed network that will simply have a thin edge and an arrow. I keep getting an edge that looks triangular. How can I get a simple line and an arrow?

```
vertice1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
vertice2 <- c("d", "e", "f")

edge.list <- data.frame(vertice1, vertice2)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edge.list, directed=TRUE)

plot(g)
```

[Directed Network with Triangular Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BUfo.png)

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Did you try in a new/clear R session? Did you set any `igraph_options()` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting the triangle that you got, but I feel certain that is just a large arrow head on the links.  Try,

```
plot(g, edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I have no idea why my plot defaulted to a large arrow size. I had started a clean session and hadn't set any options.

Comment: Are you plotting within RStudio on Windows? It seems like that causes trouble with arrows [why the graph is not proper in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685421/why-the-graph-is-not-proper-in-r)

Comment: Yes, I'm using RStudio on Windows. Can't believe I spent hours thinking it was me! :(